# KeyListener is not interacting correctly with rest of program

Tags: java, swing, graphics, keylistener

Whenever I press space or any other key I try to configure it does not change the "pixelsizemodifier" variable. I can't even get it to print to the console. I do not know where I am going wrong. Runs perfect besides that.

Sorry in advance for my crappy code. I was experimenting from memory after not writing for a while.

What I want it to do is to take a keyevent to change variables such as the pixel sizing or later things like pixel density or color.

```
package square;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class main extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    
    Random rand;
    int randomInt, boxQuantity, lineCount, ovalCount;
    static JFrame frame;
    static JPanel p;
    boolean painting = false;
    int re,gr,bl;
    Color color;
    int pixelsize , pixelsizemodifier = 10, pixeldistance;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame("Welcome!");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new main());
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        
        p = new JPanel();
        p.setVisible(true);
        
        frame.add(p);
        new main().go();
        
    } 
    
    public void go() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        rand = new Random();
        
        boxQuantity = 0;
        ovalCount = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < frame.getWidth()/10; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < frame.getHeight()/10; y++) {
                
                re = rand.nextInt(255);
                gr = rand.nextInt(255);
                bl = rand.nextInt(255);
                color = new Color(re , gr , bl);
                g.setColor(color);
                
                randomInt = rand.nextInt(4);
                pixelsize = rand.nextInt(pixelsizemodifier);
                pixeldistance = rand.nextInt(11);
                
                switch (randomInt) {
                    case 0:
                        g.fillRect(x*10, y*pixeldistance, pixelsize, pixelsize);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        g.fillRect(x*10, y*pixeldistance, pixelsize, pixelsize);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        g.fillRect(x*10, y*pixeldistance, pixelsize, pixelsize);
                        break;
                    case 3: 
                        g.fillRect(x*10, y*pixeldistance, pixelsize, pixelsize);
                        break;
                }
                boxQuantity++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("width: " + frame.getWidth()/10 + " / bq: " + boxQuantity + " / psm: " + pixelsizemodifier);
        repaint();
    }
    
    
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                pixelsizemodifier++;
                
            }
            

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                pixelsizemodifier++;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many issues:

1. class names should start with an upper case character
2. class names should be descriptive. `"main"` does not follow either of these practices.
3. Don't use static variables. All the variables in your class should be instance variables. Instance variables can be accesses by any method in your class
4. There is no need to define a "frame" variable. You class does not need to know the frame it is contained in.
5. Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)`, not paint().
6. Custom painting should only paint the current state of the component. It should NOT change the state. Therefore you should NOT be generating "random" values in the painting method. Instead you have a method that generates a random value that is added to a 2D array. Then the painting method iterates through the array to paint the representation of the value
7. Never invoke repaint() in a painting method. That is NOT how animation is done. Instead you use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation. When the Timer fires you invoke the method from above that generates your random values. That method will then invoke repaint.
8. You should not be using a KeyListener to listen for a KeyEvent. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`

The [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) has sections on:

1. Custom Painting
2. How to Use Swing Timers
3. How to Use Key Bindings.

Read the tutorial for examples on each of the above topics.

> Whenever I press space or any other key I try to configure it does not change the "pixelsizemodifier" variable

Finally, the cause of your problem:

```
    frame.getContentPane().add(new main());
    ...
    new main().go();
```

You are creating two instances of your custom class. Don't.

You only need one instance. That instance needs to be added to the frame and you need to invoke go() on that instance:

You should invoke the `go()` method in the constructor of your class.